# Converting Text to Numbers

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to convert text to numbers operating in 2 different worksheets at the same time.

I managed to write something working for a range in a current worksheet:

```
Sub ConvertTextToNumber1()
  With Range("B5:B14")
      .NumberFormat = "General"
      .Value = .Value
  End With
End Sub
```

I am trying to convert text to numbers in the below ranges:

```
string1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Virt_Summary").Range("A1:DZ50")
string2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Virt_PPTs").Range("A1:BW50")
```

Code I tried below:

```
Sub ConvertTextToNumber()

Dim string1 As Range, string2 As Range
string1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Virt_Summary").Range("A1:DZ50")
string2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Virt_PPTs").Range("A1:BW50")

  With Range(string1, string2)
  .NumberFormat = "General"
  .Value = .Value

  End With

End Sub
```

Do you have any suggestions?

Thanks a lot,

Tried multiple resources and statements.

Answer (score 1):

Add a `Range`-type parameter to your `ConvertTextToNumber` sub, and you can call it and pass in different ranges:

```vb
Sub Tester()
   With ThisWorkbook
       ConvertTextToNumber .Worksheets("Virt_Summary").Range("A1:DZ50")
       ConvertTextToNumber .Worksheets("Virt_PPTs").Range("A1:BW50")
   End with
End Sub

Sub ConvertTextToNumber(rng As Range)
  With rng
      .NumberFormat = "General"
      .Value = .Value
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot mate. Before I test it out I need to build few other thins, I will let you know once I manage to find out